# Possible orderings of points of a pair of segments

Tags: python, algorithm

Suppose `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` hold floating point numbers. Suppose it must hold that `a <= b` and `c <= d`. Given these constraints I am trying to find all of the possible orderings using only `<`, and `=`. For example `a < c = b < d` is one possible ordering. `b < c < a < d` is not, due to the constraint that `a <= b`.

Comment: This seems like a logic problem, not a coding problem. What have you tried so far?

Comment: What do you need this for?

Comment: I've tried code to generate all the possible orderings without constraints, but it uses strings, and applying the constraints on top of that becomes difficult and prone to error.

Comment: I want to write a case statement on each ordering.

Comment: What do you need the case statements for?

Comment: Brute force approach: generate all the possible permutations using `itertools`, then grind through them and filter out the ones that violate constraints.

Comment: Each ordering, or only the known to be valid ones? There are 4!=24 orders of the variables, and 2^3 = 8 operators if you only use < or =, so you want all 192 of them, or only the ones satisfying the constraints? (using > means you have undefined expressions, such as a < c < b > d which obeys the constraints for 1 < 2 < 4 > 3 but not for  1 < 2 < 4 > 1)

Comment: Good point. I should have left out `>` in the question. I will edit.

Comment: Only the valid ones based on the properties of real numbers and inequalities and that satisfy the constraints.

Comment: @Samwise That was my initial approach, but I don't know a good way to filter on all of the constraints that apply to inequalities between real numbers, plus the additional two in the question.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode The first interval is a request for data in that interval. The second interval is a buffer of data in that interval. I want to send a request to a server for the requested data that is not already in the buffer, then add it to the buffer, with various constraints on the result.

Comment: @Patrick Can't you just request a missing prefix if there is one and a missing suffix if there is one?

Answer (score 0):

If you only allow < or = as operators, then the valid expressions will have the following properties

- as the constraints only use ≤, whether the expressions use < or = does not matter
- the constraints mean a must be before b and c must be before d

You can either generate all permutations and prune those which don't have a before b and c before d in them out, or you can generate based on those constraints, by deducing:

- the first variable must be a or c
- the second variable can either be the second variable in the constraint of the first, or other option for first
- if the second is the same constraint as the first, then the other two must be the other two in order ( [a b c d] or [c d a b] )
- if the variables for the constraints are interleaved, the third and forth can be in either order

That should give:

```
a∙b∙c∙d
a∙c∙b∙d
a∙c∙d∙b
c∙d∙a∙b
c∙a∙d∙b
c∙a∙b∙d
```

where ∙ can be either < or = in any of the positions.

If you also allow > as an operator, you get some which are always valid and some which can be either valid or not.

```
a∙b>c∙d
c∙d>a∙b
```

are valid as the > order doesn't occur between any of the variables that are paired in the constraints. I think any other cases with > it breaks the transitivity so you can't know whether the result obeys the constraints or not.

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def interleave_strings(a,b):
    return ''.join(''.join(x) for x in zip_longest(a, b, fillvalue=''))

VARIABLE_ORDERINGS = ['abcd','acbd','cdab','cadb','cabd']
OPERATOR_COMBINATIONS = ['<<<','=<<','<=<','<<=','<==','=<=','==<','===']
for vars in VARIABLE_ORDERINGS:
    for ops in OPERATOR_COMBINATIONS:
        # only include a=b not b=a to elide equivalent expressions
        if ops[0] == '=' and vars[0] > vars[1]: continue
        if ops[1] == '=' and vars[1] > vars[2]: continue
        if ops[2] == '=' and vars[2] > vars[3]: continue

        print(interleave_strings(vars, ops))
```

Comment: Thank you. It would be ideal to have code to generate these, that includes the interleaving operators.

Comment: I think this produces duplicates, for example `a=b=c=d` and `a=c=b=d` are really the same case.